# Performance issue in opencv using pinvoke

Tags: c++, opencv, pinvoke

I have two C++ functions that are called from C# using pinvoke. The C++ functions both use opencv.

Function1:

```
int FaceDetector(CallBackFunc callBack, const char* absolutePathToCascadeClassifier, int webcamId, int resWidth, int resHeight) {
string fileNameStr = absolutePathToCascadeClassifier;
CascadeClassifier haar_cascade;
haar_cascade.load(fileNameStr);
if (haar_cascade.empty())
    return -1;

// Get a handle to the Video device:
VideoCapture cap(webcamId);
if (!cap.isOpened()) {
    return -2;
}

cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, resWidth);
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, resHeight);
Points3D points = { 0.5, 0.5, 1 };


Mat frame;
for (;;) {
    cap >> frame;
    Mat original = frame.clone();
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(original, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
    haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);
    if (faces.empty()){
        points = { 0.5, 0.5, 1 };
        callBack(points);
        continue;
    }
    Rect_<int> largestFace = *max_element(faces.begin(), faces.end(), compareRect);

    points.x = (largestFace.x + (largestFace.width / 2)) / (double)resWidth;
    points.y = (largestFace.y + (largestFace.height / 2)) / (double)resHeight;
    //z index is inversely proportional to rectangle area
    //take 1/4th of screen area as max rect area, 0 as min
    double maxFaceArea = ((double)resWidth * resHeight) / 4;
    if (largestFace.area() > maxFaceArea){
        points.z = 0;
    }
    else{
        points.z = 1 - sqrt(largestFace.area() / maxFaceArea);
    }
    callBack(points);
}
```

}

Function 2:

```
int FaceTracker(unsigned char* imageBuffer, int width, int height, double* points){
if (haar_cascade.empty())
    return 1;
Mat frame(Size(width, height), CV_8UC3, imageBuffer, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
Mat gray;
cvtColor(frame, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

vector< Rect_<int> > faces;
haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces);
if (faces.empty())
    return 2;

Rect_<int> largestFace = *max_element(faces.begin(), faces.end(), compareRect);
*(points) = (largestFace.x + (largestFace.width / 2)) / (double)width;
*(points + 1) = (largestFace.y + (largestFace.height / 2)) / (double)height;

//z index is inversely proportional to rectangle area
//take 1/4th of screen area as max rect area, 0 as min
double maxFaceArea = ((double)width * height) / 4;
if (largestFace.area() > maxFaceArea){
    *(points + 2) = 1;
}
else{
    *(points + 2) = sqrt(largestFace.area() / maxFaceArea);     //taking sqrt to make things linear
}
return 0;
}
```

As you can see the difference between two functions is that the first one is called only once, video capturing takes place in native code. In the second case web cam capture takes place in managed code and I call  the function each time new frame is generated. The matrix `gray` is same in both cases as far as I can tell. It has the same number of channels and same size.

My issue is that in the first case the function call `haar_cascade.detectMultiScale` takes 100 milliseconds on average, whereas in the second case the same function call takes around 300 milliseconds. Why is this so when apparently the same parameters are passed both times?

Comment: Hard to say for sure when we've only got incomplete code. You could work this out though with some debugging.

Comment: I can provide full code. I just thought it would be too cluttered.

Comment: We don't want to see all of your code. Just enough to demonstrate the issue. Anyway, your best approach is to do some debugging. You can time your code. Work out where it is spending its time. That's going to be easy for you to do. We'll have to guess.

Comment: Yes I used method from [here](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/c--Evaluating-execution-times-791.php) to assess timing. That's how I found out that the haarcascade call is the culprit. How do I proceed further into the haarcascade?